# Expressing a piecewise modular function with a single expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, modular-arithmetic

I have figured out that
$$
    \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            a(x) & \quad c(x) < 0 \\
            b(x) & \quad c(x) > 0\
        \end{array}
    \right.=\frac{(c(x)-|c(x)|)(b(x)-a(x))}{2|c(x)|}+b(x)
$$

as long as
$$c(x)\neq0$$ (Please correct me if this is wrong!)

I would like to know if and/or how this extends to modular arithmetic, i.e. expressing a piecewise modular function as a single equation. I am completely new to modular, so please keep that in mind when answering. Thanks for your time!